# Kernel Immediately Crashes when using Tensorflow with GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I am working with a Jupyter Notebook in WSL2. I can run python in any cell, I can even use Tensorflow to build a model. I can train it using the CPU. However whenever the GPU is used for training, the kernel will crash. From what I can tell from the logs, the error is:

`Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8. Error: libcuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have the latest version of Windows 10.

I am working in a WSL2 environment. Using `--list --verbose` will show this:

NAME      STATE           VERSION

- Ubuntu    Running         2
  Debian    Running         2

I have NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660. I have updated my GPU driver using the "GeForce Experience" app from Windows.

`nvidia-smi`
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.54.06              Driver Version: 536.40       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 ...    On  | 00000000:2B:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P8              14W / 130W |   1003MiB /  6144MiB |      1%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A        28      G   /Xwayland                                 N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A        28      G   /Xwayland                                 N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A       800      G   /chrome                                   N/A      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

I followed the tensorflow guide here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip

I built the distro from scratch in Debian because I already tried it in Ubuntu and got more errors. I first set up my VScode server. I installed curl and installed miniconda:
`curl https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -o Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh`

I set up my environment:
`conda create --name tf python=3.9`

I downloaded the Jupyter and python extensions for VScode because I like to work directly in VScode and not in Jupyter labs. I pip installed ipykernel. At this point, a Jupyter notebook running on the 'tf' kernel works fine.

I install the GPU dependencies:
`conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.8.0 pip install nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.6.0.163`

I configured the system path:
`mkdir -p $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d echo 'CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)"))' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib' >> $CONDA_PREFIX/etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh`

I installed tensorflow and my other notebook-dependencies:
`pip install tensorflow==2.12.`

At this point the GPU will show up:
`print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]`

Now running the entire notebook, including compiling the training images, preprocessing, etc. will work until it reaches this line: `model.fit(x=train_images, y=train_labels, epochs=10)`

I know that this is the line because it doesn't crash when I delete it. When looking through the jupyter logs, I am fairly certain this is the problem: `Could not load library libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8. Error: libcuda.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I have confirmed that libcudnn_cnn_infer.so.8 is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. it exists here: /home/user_name/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib.

In that directory, there is also a file called libcudnn.so.8. I renamed it to libcudnn.so to see if that would work, but instead it failed to find my GPU and just used my CPU instead.

I also found a file called libcudnn.so at this path:
`/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so`

So I tried adding it to LD_LIBRARY_PATH
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH /home/dog_hazard/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/:/home/dog_hazard/miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cudnn/lib:/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so`

This did nothing. Same error.

I do not know what to do. I've found similar problems online but nothing has helped me

Comment: so I got it to work. although the path to libcuda.so was CLEARLY in my path, tesnorflow continued to miss it. so I manually copied that file, and plopped it down to another directory which my path also had access to. Now it works.

Comment: I had the same problem (but under Win11 rather than Win10, Ubuntu rather than Debian), same kernel crash & error message, libraries in the same directories as yours with the same LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Your solution worked for me as well.